# Microsoft excel Power Query (windows) to VBA (Mac)

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

I have created a query which takes data from a folder, and orders the data in such a way that I need..

The problem is that it won't work on MacOs.. The get from folder function does not exist in MacOs, I understood that I need to use VBA in order to do the same thing on MacOs..

I have no clue on how to use VBA
These are some of the steps in my power query:

= Folder.Files("C:\Users\location..")
= Table.SelectRows(Source, each [Attributes]?[Hidden]? <> true)
= Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Hidden Files1", "Transform File", each #"Transform File"([Content]))

And so on..

How could I mimic these in MacOs with VBA?

Comment: In the version you tested on the Mac, what did you put for the file location instead of "Folder.Files("C:\Users\location..")"? You must have changed it as the Mac filesystem is different.

Comment: well, you see, the main problem is that I can not change it, PowerQuery does not open like on windows...
These are the indications that I can add or modify on windows, but on Mac I can not do any of that

Answer (score 0):

So here is a proposed solution, but unfortunately it runs into permission problems, which maybe someone else can help with.

First have three cells in your spreadsheet. Use the Excel name manager to name them OS, FilePath and FileName respectively. Their content is:

```
OS: =LET(vers,INFO("OSVERSION"),IFERROR(LEFT(vers,FIND(" ",vers)-1),vers))
FilePath: =IF(A1="Windows","C:\...\","/Users/.../")
FileName= report.csv
```

(obviously subsititute the actual windows & mac filepaths above)

As the start of your Power Query M code, use:

```
let
  FilePath= Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="FilePath"]}[Content]{0}[Column1],  
  FileName= Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="FileName"]}[Content]{0}[Column1],  
  Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(FilePath & FileName), [Delimiter = ",", Columns = 12, Encoding = 65001, QuoteStyle = QuoteStyle.None])
in
    Source
```

This works fine on the Windows side - I am having some problems on Mac, getting an error such as:

> Query 'FetchReport (2)' (step 'AutoRemovedColumns1') is accessing data sources that have privacy levels which cannot be used together. Please rebuild this data combination.0: